# Run short Background Task in short interval in UWP for special case alarm scenario

Tags: .net, uwp, scheduled-tasks, alarm, background-task

I need to write a special alarm app that would not know beforehand when an alarm sets off. For example one of the possible scenarios is every 15 seconds, it checks for a file, and if that file exists, a notification is sent. The timer should start when user manually starts the app or optionally on Windows startup if user grants permission.

- It's critical that the alarm cannot be too late than 1 minute, so the `TimeTrigger` 15 minutes cannot satisfy it.
- `extendedBackgroundTaskTime` capacity removes ability to publish to Windows Store. Note that requesting user permission is fine, but we need to publish it to general public Windows Store.
- `ExtendedExecutionSession` has maximum time of 10 minutes and cannot be renewed if app is not active (I may be wrong). Although there is `LocationTracking` that provides unlimited time, per documentation: "No limit. Only one app at a time may request this reason.", and my app is not for providing location tracking.
- Using alarm toast like [Building an Alarm App in Windows 8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/october/windows-8-1-building-an-alarm-app-in-windows-8-1) or [Schedule a toast notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/scheduled-toast) or `AlarmApplicationManager` requires knowing exactly when the alarm sets off, which this app does not know at that time. Also they require a Toast to show up and then an user interaction to continue processing the code.

Please advise a solution for this problem, either API or code would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, UWP apps are under power considerations. By default, they do not support long-term or high-frequency execution of background tasks. From your problem description, the technologies you listed are some implementation solutions currently provided by UWP. But currently, UWP does not provide additional background task running strategies.

Comment: That sucks :( I wish I could ask for user permission for more frequent task (as low as 1 minute, 15s is a very good scenario), even if the task must be finished quickly (it can be finished in under 5s).

Comment: I haven't looked up yet, but do you think making it a WPF app and use Windows Bridge a good workaround?

Comment: For UWP applications, unless you keep the application in the foreground and use timer detection in the foreground, background tasks are difficult to call at a frequency of 15s. The win32 application is indeed a solution, but I am not sure if it meets your needs (it only applies to desktop)